# Facebook SDKv5 Login Fails when moving directory

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am doing a very basic setup of Facebook SDK v5 login but it is failing miserably for strange reasons. It works fine when installed as per the example documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/).  I get the expected outcome printed to the screen. However, I keep getting the following error simply by trying to move the folder path of the SDK to a deeper folder:

> Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Here is a traceback of the directory path permissions:

```
namei -l /var/www/html/app/assets/backend_assets/vendor/Facebook

drwxr-xr-x root        root     /
drwxr-xr-x root        root     var
drwxr-xr-x root        root     www
drwxr-xr-x development www-data html
drwxr-xr-x development www-data app
drwxr-xr-x development www-data assets
drwxr-xr-x development www-data backend_assets
drwxr-xr-x development www-data vendor
```

The API will return a successful callback when I keep the Facebook SDK folder in the /var/www/html/app/assets/ directory, but when I try to move it deeper to say /var/www/html/app/assets/backend_assets/ the API will not issue a token and I get the error message above.

I actually want the folder to be two deeper and not sure why this would even make a difference. The SDK is loading because there would be no error message without it, however, I have a specific place for vendor SDK's and I want it to go there (/var/www/html/app/assets/backend_assets/vendor/ ). The permissions and folder onwership are the same all along the route, so I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: The SDK will try to determine the redirect_uri value automatically based on the current URL, but in some situations that can fail (for example if you try to exchange the code for a token from a different URL than the one where you created the login URL.) In those cases, you can specify the redirect URI explicitly in your call of the `getAccessToken` method (and `getLoginUrl` as well, if necessary.)

Comment: Do you have any links to  facebook login documentation that teaches you these deeper system functionality?  The documentation I have found for the php sdk is brutal, doesn't explain any features or settings.

Comment: Why would the redirect URL change if I move the required_once or include path of a the sdk?  The page is still being loaded from the same index.php

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly causes this in this instance, way too little info on how you are using it, what kind of router component (if any) your system uses, etc. The SDK allows to specify your own [`UrlDetectionInterface`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/UrlDetectionInterface/5.0.0) to handle this kind of issues; but unless you are in a really big, dynamic system where you have to perform login from a lot of different places, I think explicitly specifying the redirect URI in the mentioned method calls is easier.